# How to open .fif file format?

Tags: python, c++, file-io

I want to open a .fif file of size around 800MB. I googled and found that these kind of files can be opened with photoshop. Is there a way to extract the images and store in some other standard format using python or c++.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably an EEG or MEG data file.  The full specification is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q58whpso2jt9tx0/Fiff.pdf?dl=0), and it can be read in with the [MNE package](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python) in Python.

```
import mne
raw = mne.io.read_raw_fif('filename.fif')
```

Answer (score 1):

FIF stands for Fractal Image Format and seems to be output of the Genuine Fractals Plugin for Adobe's Photoshop. Unfortunately, there is no format specification available and the plugin claims to use patented algorithms so you won't be able to read these files from within your own software.

There however are other tools which can do fractal compression. [Here's](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/4367/print) some information about one example. While this won't allow you to open FIF files from the Genuine Fractals Plugin, it would allow you to compress the original file, if still available.

Answer (score 1):

[XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/) seems to handle FIF files, but it's windows-only. There is a MP or Multiplatform version, but it seems less complete and didn't work when I tried to view a FIF file.

Update: XnView MP, which does work on Linux and OSX claims to support FIF, but I couldn't get it to work.

Update2: There's also an open source project:[Fiasco](https://github.com/l-tamas/Fiasco) that can work with fractal images, but not sure it's compatible with the proprietary FIF format.